# Parallel Install of Visual Studio Code (vscode) and Visual Studio Code Insiders (vscode insiders): modify standard app

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10, settings, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have an annoying problem with the parallel installation of Visual Studio Code (vscode) and Visual Studio Code Insiders (vscode insiders):

typing

```sh
code .
```

In Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) always opens standard Visual Studio Code, which, as of now, has no support for WSL development. I added a right-click windows context menu "Open Folder in vscode insiders", but this doesn't establish the WSL connection. I always have to manually connect using ([vscode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_open-a-folder-in-wsl)):

```
press F1, select Remote-WSL: New Window, and use the File menu to open your folder
```

Is there a way to modify the main vscode installation, so that `code .` in WSL opens vscode insiders?

**Additional Information**

Both are installed in Windows:

- VS Code: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe`
- VS Code Insiders: `C:\Users\\[User]\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\Code - Insiders.exe`

Typing `which code` in WSL returns:

```sh
which code
/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code
```

→ Path to the wrong install

Comment: Where are those vscode installed? In Windows side (exe) or in WSL (/usr/bin)?

Comment: I've updated my question above!

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks @Biswapriyo for pointing me in the right direction.

The answer is to use:

```sh
code-insiders .
```

.. in the WSL folder you which to open in Windows VS Code, *instead of* (as suggested in the [vscode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_open-a-folder-in-wsl)):

```sh
code .
```

I found out by typing `where code` in Windows console, which pointed towards `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code`. I had a look in the same folder in `Insiders` (`C:\Users\\[User]\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\bin`), which contains a file `code-insiders.cmd`.

The problem could originate from using `Chocolatey` package manager for installing and updating VS Code. VS Code Insiders is not available for `Choco`, which is why I installed it the regular way. I assume, everytime `Choco` updates VS Code, the main code install is overwritten (because I remember that initially `code .` would open Insiders).